# Retrieve user activities with their associated resources within time range in gridDB

Tags: python, timestamp, griddb

I’ve a working model stored in GridDB where all the entities are in a complex relationship. This data model includes information about users, their activities on site and from which resources they’re interacting with and at what time. This particular data includes every user with a unique identifier, activities that  are timestamped, resources with attributes like type, location and status

I’m providing just  a sample dataset for the reference, I can’t provide the real data sets due to confidentiality.
Sample Data Sets from UserActivity model:
[
{"user_id": 1, "activity": "Login", "timestamp": "2023-01-01T08:00:00"},
{"user_id": 2, "activity": "Create Document", "timestamp": "2023-01-01T09:30:00"},
{"user_id": 1, "activity": "Access Resource", "resource_id": "A123", "timestamp": "2023-01-01T10:15:00"}
]

I want my code to work in a scenario where it can retrieve the data from all the activities performed by a user in a given time range including the details associated with their resources.